Proof of Schur-Weyl duality
$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{|#1\rangle}$
I am reading an article (Joy Lie, 2019, "The Quantum Schur Transform and its Applications"), about the quantum Schur transform. There, it is stated that one can follow from Schur's lemma that the action of $Q(U)P(s)$ (will be defined below):
$$
Q(U)P(s)=\bigoplus_{\alpha,\beta}I_{m_{\alpha,\beta}}\otimes q_\beta(U)\otimes p_\alpha(s),
$$
where $q_\beta(U)$ (for a unitary matrix $U$) are irreps of $Q(U)$, acting like
$$
Q(U)\ket{\psi_1}\otimes...\otimes\ket{\psi_n}=U\ket{\psi_1}\otimes...\otimes U\ket{\psi_n}
$$
and $p_\beta(s)$ (for a permutation $s$) are irreps of $P(s)$, acting like
$$
P(s)\ket{\psi_1}\otimes...\otimes\ket{\psi_n}=\ket{\psi_{s^{-1}(1)}}\otimes...\otimes \ket{\psi_{s^{-1}(n)}}.
$$
How exactly does this argument work. Why does the decomposition of $Q(U)P(s)$ looks like this and how does this follow from Schur's lemma?
